# Azure App Configuration - How to get the latest configuration in App Service

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-app-configuration

**After value in app configuration have changed,**

[image]

**the configuration in Azure App Service is not changed even I restart it**

[image]

I wonder how can I make app service get the new configuration without any code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force your App Service instance to reload the value from App Configuration by making any change to your existing application settings in App Service. According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configuration-references#reference-syntax):

> Any configuration change to the app that results in a site restart causes an immediate refetch of all referenced key-values from the App Configuration store.

You could create a dummy application setting in App Service and change its value whenever you want to reload key-values from App Configuration.

Comment: Excellent.  But beware of mature applications having redundant config items that duplicate a connection string. Your value may be in there twice (!).

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make app service get the new configuration without any code?

- To get the new configuration, navigate to Azure Portal and open Azure App Service.
- Go to settings of your App Service=> Configuration=> Application Settings=> click on Add New Application Setting.

[image]

Enter the setting name in "Name" and its value in "Value" fields as shown below.

[image]

Once you add these settings in the configuration section of your App service, you can access these settings in your application for further use.

---

> **the configuration in Azure App Service is not changed even I restart it**

AFAIK, the configuration values of Azure App Configuration will not reflect directly in the configuration of Azure App Service.

- Azure App Service has its own configuration system, which includes application settings and connection strings that can be managed directly in the Azure portal.
- You can fetch configuration values from Azure App Configuration in your App Service programmatically using SDKs or libraries (Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration nuget package).

**References:**
[Quickstart: Create an Azure App Configuration store | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-app-configuration-create?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: I guess, the question is about getting the updated configuration value. The old value is returned

Comment: yes, as what @MarkusMeyer said.

Comment: My English isn't very good, so I would appreciate it if you could help me improve my description.

Comment: My bad, will update the answer as per your ask